# Can no longer access TFS from workstation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

All of the sudden I can no longer access my TFS 2010 server. It is on the same network as my laptop. I have made no changes to anything. I worked on it one day and then the next day VS2012 and 2010 can't connect. I can also not connect to the web UI from the outside either.

I have VS2010 installed on my server and it can connect just fine. I have looked at my services on my laptop and found nothing about TFS or Visual Studio.

What I have tried.
Restarting the server
Restarting my laptop.
Resetting the TFS user account on my server.
Restarting the web server that TFS runs under.
Checked the server logs for errors.
ipconfig /flushdns
Using VS2010 and VS2012. With all updates.
Turned off Bitdefender firewall.
Firewall on server is turned off.
Ping server name. This works.
RDC into server via same server name. This works.
Connecting to TFS from VS2010 on the server. This works.

I would say this is a DNS issue but I can get to my server just fine except when TFS is involved. It seems like there is a communication issue from an outside source to TFS.

Any ideas on why access from any other source than the server would just stop?

Comment: Have you had a look in the IIS logs for the TFS web site? The one running on port 8080. Can you see the connections hitting IIS?

Comment: So here is what happens. when I tried to add the server here is a truncated log snip.

2013-09-01 23:50:06 /tfs/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx
2013-09-01 23:51:27 /Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx
2013-09-01 23:51:27 /tfs/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx
2013-09-01 23:51:27 /TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
2013-09-01 23:51:27 /tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
2013-09-01 23:51:27 /Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx

Comment: All of this flows in after VS2010 is unable to add the server and I have to cancel out. It starts at IP 192.168.1.10 on port 8080 and goes to 192.168.116 as it should.

Comment: Did you try to enter the IP instead of the server name as TFS in VS TeamExplorer? What error message exactly do you get when connecting with TFS?

Comment: It just says it can't connect. I can get to the server based on the logs. The logs listed above seem to indicate a possible permissions issue. Still working on it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Bitdefender too and for my final hope to solve this problem, I went to Control Panel > Uninstall a program > and Repair the Bitdefender, TFS came back!

While Bitdefender was repairing, I was able to access TFS Web site in the same network. Restarted Windows and the problem didn't show up again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually upgraded to the latest version of BD and it solve the issue. I am not sure what happened but BD seemed to be the issue.